# using array_sum() except last value

Tags: php, arrays, sum

```
$payamount = [5, 10, 15, 20, 60];
```

I want to sum all the elements of `$payamount`, except for the last element, like this: 5 + 10 + 15 + 20  <strike>+ 60</strike>.

I've tried using `array_sum($payamount)`, but that sums all the elements of the array, whereas I want to exclude the last element.

How can I do this?

Comment: If it is always the last element you need to remove, use [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) to remove it and get its value, then `array_sum()` the original array (which is now shorter)

Comment: Nice suggestion. Thanks @MichaelBerkowski.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array_sum($payamount) - end($payamount)
```

> [end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) — Set the internal pointer of an array to its last element

Answer (score 3):

You could [`array_slice`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) off the last element and [`array_sum`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) that array like this:

```
array_sum(array_slice($payamount, -1))
```

Or, like [@Michael Berkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46505810/using-array-sum-except-last-value/46505933#comment79965952_46505810) said, you could [`array_pop`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) the last element off  and [`array_sum`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) that array:

```
array_sum(array_pop($payamount))
```

These ways, you aren't setting the array's internal pointer, unlike [`end`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

Comment: This is more practical answer. Two options with two different nice answer :)